# Board Assembly double sided vs single sided

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

I am willing to manufacture a PCB from China, but  I am wondering how much the cost will be deference between double-sided or single-sided assembly, rough estimation will help.

Thanks

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/132197/single-vs-double-sided-pcb-assembly-costs/263087

Answer (score 1):

It will depends on your PCB complexity number and size. But they will be pretty much the same price.As they have the same complexity to produce.

Here is an example from PCBway
1 Layer :
[image]

2 Layers:
[image]

Assembly will depend on the stencil price, usually around 100-200$ in my experience.

Comment: I am asking for the assembling, not just the layout, is placing components on the bottom layer will increase board cost?

Comment: Assembly will depend on the stencil price, usually around 100-200$ in my experience.

Comment: .. which implies a higher cost because you need two stencils? Either way the right answer is to ask the assembler for their pricing!

Comment: They will usually use an empty space on the same sencil to print the components footprints if you have just few of them on the other side, so it won't cost that much in plus for this kind of situations.

Comment: Laser-cut steel stencils in China are around $10 including frame and you can put both sides on one stencil. Two passes through the machines though.

Answer (score 0):

The one off cost will be much higher.

1. First they will need two stencils (see comment above)
2. They will need a special adapter tray (aka "solder palet") to hold the components while heating the PCB through the oven. Maybe in China they can do it for $300 or less but it can also cost over $1000.
3. Encoding the pick and place machine is more complex. It may not affect the price much. But it's a good to ask if it does.

Once this is paid for, the cost per PCB assembly will be only a little bit higher but not so much.

Cost of PCB should be the same.

Use this solution only if board area is limited.